# How to run hidden API in android studio for Bluetooth Headset class?

Tags: java, android

I want to run the following apis:

`public void setForceScoAudio(boolean forced);`

`public boolean connectAudio();`

but i am unable to include them in my project. I have used reflection but it does not work and gives "METHOD NOT FOUND EXCEPTION" during run time. Please help me run these methods.Any help is appreciated.

I did this

```
Class c = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothHeadset"); 
Object myobj = c.newInstance(); 
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("setForceScoAudio",boolean.class); 
m.invoke(myobj,true);
```

but i got this error
W/System.err: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class has no zero argument constructor .

Then i tried this:
`BluetoothHeadset.class.getDeclaredMethod("setForceScoAudio",boolean.class)`
and got this error
W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setForceScoAudio [boolean].

Comment: `I have used reflection` show how you did.

Comment: please never try to post code in comments, edit question and format the code.

Comment: I have made the changes .Please review it

Comment: Firstly, you can get `android.bluetooth.BluetoothHeadset`'s class as follows: `Class c = android.bluetooth.BluetoothHeadset.class;`. Then `BluetoothHeadset` does not have empty constructor. Check it's source to see which arguments does it have: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/365522a828f529593aa87e4d5a22f0cf2460c45a/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.java

Comment: It takes context and service listener but how to pass these ,I am unable to understand .Can you please take a look at "public void setForceScoAudio(boolean forced); " this method ,if it works via reflection.Please try to run it once ,your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: you need to call constructor with parameters via reflection. How to do that you can easily find using search. You have to use search before asking, please remember.